# Overlay local patch on top of current thing

Tags: git

I have some repository-specific dev tools that I am working on, and I am working on them "in parallel" with the other tasks––they are not part of my current task, but I am using them to work, and in the course of working I might improve them to add a missing feature here or there.

What I would like is to "overlay" this dev tools patch on top of whatever I am currently working on, and perhaps switch to committing to the overlay now and again.  Does git support this kind of workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple commits on these dev-tools, I think you might use a separate branch that will be branched off of your current work, and that you will rebase when you need to switch between branches of your current work.

---

Suppose you have the following commit tree:

```
              D --- E < branch `devtools`
             /
A --- B --- C  < branch `currentwork`
       \
        F < branch `otherwork`
```

---

If you've fetched a new commit on `currentwork` from your remote and want to update your `devtools` branch, simply run

```
$ git rebase currentwork
```

Your commit tree will look like following (assuming `G` is the new commit you fetched):

```
                    D' --- E' < branch `devtools`
                   /
A --- B --- C --- G  < branch `currentwork`
       \
        F < branch `otherwork`
```

---

If you need to do something with your devtools with code from branch `otherwork`, run

```
$ git rebase currentwork --onto=otherwork
```

and the tree will look like:

```
A --- B --- C  < branch `currentwork`
       \
        F < branch `otherwork`
         \
          D' --- E' < branch `devtools`
```

---

You might also want to push your devtools branch to a remote so that you don't lose your work, but remember that after rebases you'll have to force-push it (`git push -f`) because the updates will not be fast-forward.

Comment: Hm, seems like I would need to work on `devtools` constantly to have access to the tools, and momentarily switch to `currentwork` to commit "normally".  A bit cumbersome...